# Do I need to run Captcha and Mollom simultaneously?

Tags: 7, advertising, captcha

Just wondering if I have [Mollom](https://www.drupal.org/project/mollom) installed and running successfully on a D7 site, if I still need to keep [Captcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha) enabled?

I'm getting double captcha forms with both enabled.

Comment: The only possible answer is "it depends". Do you have any reason to believe Mollom will fail to recognize some threats? If so, you need other layer. If no, no.

Comment: No. There is no need to have both enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're satisfied with the [Mollom](https://www.drupal.org/project/mollom) module, then I don't think it makes sense to also leave the [Captcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha) module enabled/installed.

However, **if** you're looking for some kind of extra protection/layer but without those double captcha forms, **then** you may want to consider replacing [Captcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha) with the [Honeypot](https://www.drupal.org/project/honeypot) module. Because of the technique used by Honeypot, you don't risk to have double captcha forms in that case.

Some more details about the Honeypot module (from its project page):

> ... uses both the honeypot and timestamp methods of deterring spam bots from completing forms on your Drupal site ([read more here](http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/introducing-honeypot-form-spam)). These methods are effective against many spam bots, and are not as intrusive as CAPTCHAs or other methods which [Punish the user](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPOezLL398U).

**Note**: even if you don't want to consider using the Honeypot module (for whatever reason), **keep "the message" in mind** about what that link quoted from its project page ([Punish the user](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPOezLL398U)) is trying to explain whenever your researching similar modules.

Comment: I've had captcha disabled for the last 24+ hours and so far, no spam post on my webforms...